# Apache Camel 3.X saga compensation failed

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel

I have problem with saga compensation action on camel-springboot 3.X. When I used camel 2.X on same project everything works. On version 3 when call to '/api/pay' end with error, no compensation action invoke. Same code on internal LRA implementation works. Any idea how to fix it?

```
    from("timer:clock?period=20s")
        .saga()
        .setHeader("id", header(Exchange.TIMER_COUNTER))
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .log("Executing saga #${header.id}")
        .to("http://localhost:7001/api/train/buy/seat")
        .to("http://localhost:7003/api/flight/buy");
  
    rest().post("/train/buy/seat")
        .param().type(RestParamType.header).name("id").required(true).endParam()
        .route()
        .saga()
        .propagation(SagaPropagation.SUPPORTS)
        .option("id", header("id"))
        .compensation("direct:cancelPurchase")
        .log("Buying train seat #${header.id}")
        .to("http://localhost:7002/api/pay?bridgeEndpoint=true&type=train")
        .log("Payment for train #${header.id} done");

    from("direct:cancelPurchase")
        .log("Train purchase #${header.id} has been cancelled");
```

External LRA configuration:

```
camel:
  service:
    lra:
      enabled: true
      coordinator-url: http://localhost:8080
      local-participant-url: http://localhost:XXXX/api
  lra:
    enabled: true
    coordinator-url: http://localhost:8080
    local-participant-url: http://localhost:XXXX/api
```